# jUnit Unexpected method call DAO Easymock check User

Tags: java, mocking, tdd, dao, easymock

I have a problem with testing check user method from DAO.
Here is the code:

```
private UserService service;
private UserDao mockDAO;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    service=new UserService();
    mockDAO=createMock(UserDao.class);
    service.setUserDao(mockDAO);
}

@Test
public void testCheckUserLogin(){

    User results=new User();
    User test=new User();
    test.setUsername("x");
    test.setPass("y");


   EasyMock.expect(mockDAO.checkUser(test)).andReturn(results.getIdUser());        
   EasyMock.replay(mockDAO);
   assertEquals(service.login(test),service.login(results));
   EasyMock.verify(mockDAO);
}
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call UserDao.checkUser(com.sot.car.model.User@4e527622):
```

I don't know why I get this error? I have added `EasyMock.expect` for the method check user

Answer (score 0):

Because, When we use objects in Mocking, we need to use matchers to perform object Comparision.

In your case, you can either set a Matcher to match it or if you are happy with any User Object then use EasyMock.isA(User.class)
e.g.
EasyMock.expect(mockDAO.checkUser(EasyMock.isA(User.class))).andReturn(results.getIdUser());

OR

EasyMock.expect(mockDAO.checkUser(test)).andReturn(results.getIdUser());
EasyMock.reportMatcher(new MatcherClass()); // Refer : http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock2_2_Documentation.html